# Java - format double value as dollar amount

Tags: java, formatting, double

I need to format the double "amt" as a dollar amount println("$" + dollars + "." + cents) such that there are two digits after the decimal.

What is the best way to go about doing so?

```
if (payOrCharge <= 1)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the payment amount:");
    double amt = keyboard.nextDouble();
    cOne.makePayment(amt);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("The original balance is " + cardBalance + ".");
    System.out.println("You made a payment in the amount of " + amt + ".");
    System.out.println("The new balance is " + (cardBalance - amt) + ".");
}
else if (payOrCharge >= 2)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the charged amount:");
    double amt = keyboard.nextDouble();
    cOne.addCharge(amt);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("The original balance is $" + cardBalance + ".");
    System.out.println("You added a charge in the amount of " + amt + ".");
    System.out.println("The new balance is " + (cardBalance + amt) + ".");
}
```

Comment: Look at **String.format()**, by the way double is not a good type for keeping currency amounts, use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 66):

Use [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()):

```
double amt = 123.456;    

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(formatter.format(amt));
```

Output:

```
$123.46
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, you need to import the util though with

"import java.text.NumberFormat;"

at the top.

Comment: I had to manipulate it a little to make sure I got the $ sign.  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale.US)

Comment: This answer works, till you factor that you did not explicitly set the local. Which is the issue I just came across in my android app, where the user has UK set as their local for a US app (relic code, I did not write). Good to note this pitfall, else you will get incorrect monies values.

Comment: If you want to set the locale, you will need to `import java.util.Locale;` as well. Note also that `Locale` is always spelled with a capital "L".

Comment: How to get it replace 2 decimal places? Or 5?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(amt));
```

That will give you a print out with always 2dp.

But really, you should be using BigDecimal for money, because of floating point issues

Answer (score 8):

Use `DecimalFormat` to print a decimal value in desired format e.g.

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println("$" + dFormat.format(amt));
```

If you wish to display $ amount in US number format than try:

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.00");
System.out.println("$" + dFormat.format(amt));
```

Using `.00`, it always prints two decimal points irrespective of their presence. If you want to print decimal only when they are present then use `.##` in the format string.

Comment: _...then use .## in the format string._   - this will show you $5.5 instead of $5.50

Answer (score 5):

You can use printf for a one liner

```
System.out.printf("The original balance is $%.2f.%n", cardBalance);
```

This will always print two decimal places, rounding as required.

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDecimal instead of double for currency types. 
In Java Puzzlers book we see:

```
System.out.println(2.00 - 1.10);
```

and you can see it will not be 0.9.

String.format() has patterns for formatting numbers.